# Add multiple items to single azure row

Tags: sql, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I currently have a table in Azure with two columns, `Text` and `Name`. I am trying to make it so that my app takes user entered data and creates a new row and fills both columns, here is my code:

```
Table name = new Table { Name = Globals.userName };
await MobileService.GetTable<Table>().InsertAsync(name);

Table text = new Table { Text = Globals.textEntered };
await MobileService.GetTable<Table>().InsertAsync(text);
```

This properly sends the data up to my table however it creates two rows instead of one. How do I get it to create one row.

Comment: Well, never used xamarin but it appears you made two tables and SQL only has one. So you seem to be calling an insert twice (hence two rows). Are you able to send multiple values in a single call like `{ Name = Globals.userName, Text = Globals.textEntered }`?

Comment: @JacobH it work, thanks! feel free to make that an answer so I can mark it as the solution.